# Itertools groupby to group list using another list

Tags: python, list

In pandas you can use an equivalent in length Series to `GroupBy` another one, for example:

```
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,-2,-4,-3,1,2])
g = np.sign(s).diff().fillna(0).abs().cumsum()
s.groupby(g).count()

0.0    3
2.0    3
4.0    2
dtype: int64
```

Is it possible to do the same using `itertools.groupby`? Thus using another list to create groups from the current one? Or perhaps using some key? As long as it gives me an idea of how to solve this case `[1,1,1,-2,-4,-3,1,2]` to create groups according to the sings would be great.

Expected output:

```
[3,3,2]
```

Comment: groupby has a key parameter

Comment: Yes, so how could it be possible to solve this example using it?

Comment: Yes @juanpa.arrivillaga, but I know its a nice option to group lists by their items. And I could think of the Pandas equivalent to give an example of what I wanted to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the general case of grouping one iterable based on the matching value in another iterable, you can just make a cheaty `key` function that iterates the other iterable, e.g. using your original `s` and `g`:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> print([(k, len(list(grp))) for k, grp in groupby(s, key=lambda _, ig=iter(g): next(ig))])
[(0.0, 3), (2.0, 3), (4.0, 2)]
```

The `key` function accepts the value from `s` and ignores it, instead returning the matching value from iterating `g` manually (the defaulted second argument caches an iterator created from `g`, then `next` is used to manually advance it each time; pass a second argument to `next` to silently ignore mismatched lengths and simply substitute in a default value).

Obviously, for this specific case there are [better approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54014270/364696), but I'm answering the general question asked, not the specific example.

Comment: Yes quite a hacky way I would say. Nice though. I see that there is no simple or obsvious way of doing this as it seems. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
from itertools import groupby


data =  [1,1,1,-2,-4,-3,1,2]

result = [sum(1 for _ in group) for _, group in groupby(data, lambda x: x<= 0)]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[3, 3, 2]
```

The statement: `sum(1 for _ in group)` counts the number of elements in the group. The key `lambda x: x<= 0` is the *sign* function.

Comment: Minor quibble: `np.sign` returns `-1`, `0` or `1`, so the grouping for an input with `0` values would differ between the OP's code and yours. You'd need a more complete `sign` function to handle that.